# how to fade in and out a layer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I need to implement a very simple animation and I must use Core Animation to do it. The animation is after I click a button, a view fade in with 2 seconds, and after 10 seconds, it fade out, but I don't know how to do it with Core Animation, I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The Core Animation Programming Guide has a pretty good, basic example of what you want to do with an explicit CABasicAnimation object:

```
theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
theAnimation.duration=2.0;
theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
[theLayer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
```

As far as the 10-second delay you want, you can use GCD to wait 10 seconds, and then perform the exact same thing in reverse:

```
dispatch_time_t time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10000000000); // 10 seconds
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^()
{
    // Same thing, but with the fromValue/toValue reversed
});
```

**EDIT:  Fixed the fromValue/toValue values

Comment: but I need to change the layer value stick, I think I can use animation.beginTime?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I need to change the layer value stick". You mean you need the layer's opacity to stay the same during the 10 second pause?